# AWS WAF block url was lacked

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-waf

I'm using AWS WAF to block matched URL =  "/login"

My context:

- `example.com` (not block)
- `example.com/login` (block)

Model: Internet -> ALB (with WAF) -> Web service (EC2) (nginx)

When the user accessed the login page directly (`https://example.com/login`) -> the request was **blocked**. WAF worked!

But when the user accessed the main page `https://example.com` and after that, they go `https://example.com/login`, the request was **not blocked**

Press ctrl + F5, page /login was blocked

What happens is going on and how to fix that? Thank!

This is my rule on WAF
[image]

[image]

Comment: You're using nginx on your instance. It looks like once you're on the instance, nginx is actually routing the requests internally on the instance, meaning, it's not making the request outside to the internet (which would go through the WAF)

Comment: No, It can not. Because I request from internet, so all traffic must go to ALB and then EC2 instance

Comment: I think have a problem with cache control. When I press ctrl + F5, the login page was blocked. If I just press F5, the login page was not blocked

Comment: How do they navigate to /login? Are you hosting a SPA app on your EC2 instance?

Comment: @Radu Diță , yes, my app was hosted on EC2  
`**How do they navigate to /login**`
After go to main site `https://example.com`, just edit address  by adding `/login`, request did not blocked